# oauth version 1 missing authentication credentials

Tags: oauth

### When I try to execute OAuth v1 request I got

"Response{code=401, message='Unauthorized', body='null', headers={Keep-Alive=timeout=60, Transfer-Encoding=chunked, null=HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized, Server=CodeBig, WWW-Authenticate=OAuth realm="classified.net", Connection=keep-alive, CodeBig-Error-Message=missing authentication credentials, Date=Sun, 16 Oct 2016 08:16:16 GMT, Via=1.1 CodeBig, Content-Type=text/plain}}"###

Here is a code snippet of using **scribejava**

```
String apiKey = "fsfsfsf";
        String apiSecret = "fsfsfsfsf";
        String PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL = "https://somerealm.net/";
        OAuth10aService service = new ServiceBuilder().apiKey(apiKey).apiSecret(apiSecret).signatureType(SignatureType.QueryString).build(new MyAOuthv1());

OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.POST, PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL, service);
request.addOAuthParameter(OAuthConstants.TIMESTAMP, service.getApi().getTimestampService().getTimestampInSeconds());
        request.addOAuthParameter(OAuthConstants.NONCE, service.getApi().getTimestampService().getNonce());
        request.addOAuthParameter(OAuthConstants.CONSUMER_KEY, "blahblahblah");
        request.addOAuthParameter(OAuthConstants.CONSUMER_SECRET, "blahblahblah");
        request.addOAuthParameter(OAuthConstants.SIGN_METHOD, service.getApi().getSignatureService().getSignatureMethod());
        request.addOAuthParameter(OAuthConstants.VERSION, "1.0");
        request.addOAuthParameter(OAuthConstants.SIGNATURE, getSignature(service, request));
request.addPayload("{\"id\":12345,\"message\":\"some text\"}");
request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

Response response = request.send();
```

However If I use firefox's REST Client I get it working.
What is wrong? OAuth vesrion is 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use OAuth10aService::signRequest method?

Comment: I do not have a token.